# OpenLayers map doesn't get loaded correctly

Tags: javascript, asp.net, debugging, openlayers

I'm making an ASP.NET site with an OpenLayers map, but in IE it is always loading and in Chrome it says, that the site doesn't react, after a while. 
The Script is inside a content tag.
And I'm using release 2.13.1.
 
This is the code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/OpenLayers.js" ></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/expand.js"></script>

    <!-- map built with OpenLayers api on OpenStreetMap -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");
        map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

        epsg4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); // WGS 1984 projection
        projectTo = map.getProjectionObject(); // The map projection (Spherical Mercator)

        // Define center-point
        var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(8.2891666666666666666666666, 46.8344444444444444444).transform(epsg4326, projectTo);
        map.setCenter(lonLat, 8);

    </script>
```

Is my link wrong or did I forget something else?

Comment: try to give height or width to div like <style type="text/css">
html,body,#mapdiv {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
}
</style>

Answer (score 0):

You're using OpenLayers 2 syntax with the OpenLayers 3 library. One key difference is rather than saying

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");
```

You want to use

```
var map = new ol.Map("mapdiv");
```

You'll need to correct the other instances where you use 'OpenLayers' instead of 'ol'.

Here's a [link](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/doc/quickstart.html) to the getting started with OpenLayers 3 documentation.

Comment: Oh, so I was using the rigth syntax first, because I used an other js, which was actually version 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this will work

```
<html>
<head>
<title>OpenLayers Demo</title>
<style type="text/css">
html,body,#mapdiv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
</style>

<script src="../js/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/ol-theme-style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="mapdiv"></div>
<script>
map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");
map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

epsg4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); //WGS 1984 projection
projectTo = map.getProjectionObject(); //The map projection (Spherical Mercator)

var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(73.8567, 18.5203).transform(epsg4326, projectTo);

var zoom = 14;
map.setCenter(lonLat, zoom);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```